# Activity indicator not animating=iphone

Tags: iphone

In my application i am uploading some images to the servelet, which takes some time to complete upload. I have implemented an uiactivityviewer using IB and connected it to an outlet named acticityIndicator. But when i call 
[activityIndicator startsAnimating];
nothing is happening!!!
What might be the problem.
i've debugged the code,
the statement is executing, but nothing happens!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you performing your uploading on the main thread, or kicking off a background thread to do it?

If the former then you are blocking the UI thread so it doesn't have a chance to update the activity indicator.

Comment: i'm using the former one, but i think i am not blocking the ui Thread, because, the animator is called first and the http request is called later

Comment: The main thread pumps a message queue. When you do work on the main thread it is not pumping the queue so no more UI events, including animations, can be processed. You need to complete work as quickly as possible on the main thread - handing off any "long-running" work to background threads as necessary (fortunately this, and calling back to the main thread, are quite easy in Cocoa/Touch)

Comment: i'm a newbie to programming and eventually doen't know threading or the implementation of it.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately I don't think you can escape it to do what you want to do here. As I said it's not as scary is it might be on other platforms for simple things like this. I'm not near my Mac right now, but I suggest you have a look at the docs for the threading guide.